# Ayuda en listar una DB en navbar Django

Tags: django

estoy creando un proyecto en django pero tengo un problema a la hora de generar los "eventos" en el navbar. Quiero listar todos los "eventos" de la pagina y funciona bien cuando estoy en home, pero a la hora de entrar a un evento o perfil de usuario se pierde la llamada a la DB.

Probe con el navbar dentro de base.html y tambien como html externo e importandolo.

mi navbar

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Eventos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        {% for eventosos in evento_list %}
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{%url 'evento_detalle' eventosos.slug%}">{{eventosos.titulo}}</a>
                        {%endfor%}
                    </div>
                </li>
```

y mi model.py es este

```
class Evento(models.Model):
titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
resumen = models.TextField()
estado = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)
img_evento = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagenes_eventos_principal')

def __str__(self):
    return self.titulo
```

como digo, en home funciona perfecto pero al momento de entrar a otra pagina ya no aparece la lista

Comment: Quiza te genera algun error ? y sugiero que uses de la siguiente manera para el detalle tu url "{%  url 'mi_app:evento_detalle' eventosos.slug %}" y "evento_detalle" no deberia recibir tu "pk" es decir "eventosos.pk" ?

Comment: Estuve viendo, lo que pasa es que en el views.py el home es un listview pero en las demas paginas son detailview por lo cual no posee la lista de eventos. Y lo de evento detalle funciona correctamente, redirecciona bien a cada evento.

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos tu views.py por favor?

Comment: Hola Sluggma has pensado en utilizar un [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/)? De esta forma podrías pasar tu contexto independiente al view